# I cannot install from CD or USB

Tags: installation, troubleshooting

Since the Ubuntu iso file is too big for a CD I put it on a DVD but it does not get recognized on boot up. Is this because it is a DVD so I need to get a high capacity CD.

I figured no sweat I will do a USB install. I used the Universal USB installer on a clean 16 GB thumb drive. It boots to a screen saying UBUNTU with progress dots and hangs there. On retry I get:

```
Kernal panic-not syncing
drm_kms_helper ---switching to text console
```

Then it hangs.

This happens with either my original drive with a corrupted Windows 7 installed or a new blank SSD.

Any suggestions.

Comment: It will work on a DVD, is just that some documentation just seem s to refer to CDs generally as anything that will go in a disk drive.

Comment: Then I wonder what is wrong there, that it will not try to boot from the DVD? I have had other odd problems with the writer as in Windows system images that end up not working, which is why my Windows is now dead, to me anyway. I'm not paying for Windows again if I can help it which is why I am trying to get going with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting from USB again. As soon as you get the purple screen with the keyboard icon at the bottom, press ENTER (this is shown at the very beginning before you get the Ubuntu logo).

Now choose your language. At the bottom you see a list of F-keys for extra options. There is a [help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options) with more information on the available option. In your case I would try pressing **F6** and selecting **nomodeset**. Then continue to boot.

This disables [kernel mode setting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting) which causes problems with some graphics hardware on install.

Comment: @user220615 Can you please mark the question answered than (check the checkmark on the answer that helped you).